# Data on benefits of show password reset form

Tags: password, reset

Most UX designers are clear that having 1 new password field with a mechanism to show the password is a better user experience than using 2 fields for 'New password' and 'Confirm password'. Is there any data available to indicate a reduction in helpdesk calls or similar with implementing a single field approach?

Comment: Struggling to see where in that post there is evidence of the reduction in the number of calls - can you be more specific?

Comment: You're just after raw data? Good luck with that, comment deleted.

Comment: Not raw data, analysed data ideally. We have a lot of UX claims that a show/hide approach is better; I'm just looking for someone to say 'We tried it and it was better / worse because ...'. There's surely some research that's been done into this.

Comment: "Most UX designers are clear that having 1 new password field with a mechanism to show the password is a better..." - Can you provide references to backup this statement? This practice has serious security consequences.

Comment: I agree with @Izhaki.  I've not heard claims that `show password` provides better UX.  Single-field password inputs are popular because they reduce UX friction.  When single-fields are implemented, they very rarely have a show-password button.

Comment: There's a lot of literature on it, e.g. Jakob Nielsen at http://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/; Lukew at http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1653; Bruce Schneier ar https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna answer this with some information that @Peter provided in the comments:

Like he said, there is a lot of information widely available about why you should not use Password Masking and how it has a negative spin on UX. Here are some resources from people who really know their stuff in terms of UX.

[Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/) has an article on why you should stop password masking.

> Usability suffers when users type in passwords and the only feedback they get is a row of bullets. Typically, masking passwords doesn't even increase security, but it does cost you business due to login failures

[Luke Wrobelski](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1653) has an article in which he talks about the usability issues of passwords on web and especially mobile.

> The situation is even worse on mobile where small screens and imprecise fingers are the norm

[Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html) article provides his opinion on why password masking is bad.

> Of course, a truly skilled criminal can simply look at the keyboard and note which keys are being pressed. So, password masking doesn't even protect fully against snoopers

[Ux Movement](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-password-masking-can-hurt-your-sign-up-form/) has an article on why password masking can hurt your sign up process.

> When users sign up on a website, they expect a no-hassle, worry-free form to fill out. But masking their password could prevent that.

[Smashing Magazing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/26/password-masking-hurt-signup-form/) provide an article in which they explain the problems with password masking and how you could improve password masking.

> Displaying their password in plain text that one time when they are alone is probably not as a significant security risk as we tend to think

Albeit you could take this information with a bit of salt but I respect the writers of these articles and believe they know what they are talking (writing) about so I would cherish the information.